# Weird rigging issues (mismatch in scale and movements)

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, armature, bones

I am trying to complete a rig for my first character and faced with a few problems. I believe that solution is simple but I can not find it in search:/

The first problem appears after Automatic Weights applied: mismatch between the mesh and rig in sizes

[image]

it was corrected with a "keep transform" checkbox, however movements in pose mode do not match:
[image]

REMARK: the figure was scaled before to avoid "bone heat weighting: failed to find solution..." error
[image]

blender file: [link](https://pasteall.org/blend/737c54046b6a4e559e46ce581435dd3b)

Comment: I did not understand much of the question text. If a character is over-moving upon posing, check that you do not have duplicate armature modifiers.

Comment: hello, could you please share your character + armature? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sure: https://pasteall.org/blend/737c54046b6a4e559e46ce581435dd3b

Comment: the difference in sizes (screenshot 1) happens when you did not apply the *Scale* to your mesh and metarig. Also, apply *Location* and *Rotation* => *All Transformations* with CTRL+A in object mode. Furthermore, it looks like you're trying to bind the mesh to the metarig. You can do so if you want. But you will have a very simple rig and this is *not* the way how to use Rigify. It's metarig => generate rig => use the generated rig